# Is there any way to give access to particular node to some user without authentication?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase database looks like below:
[image]
Suppose I have 50 users and I want to give access to node `code-1` to user 1-20, `code-2` to user 21-40 and `code-3` to user 41-50. I have some problem and I don't want to use `firebase authentication`. Is there any way to do so? like sending data from user to firebase and then complete checking in `Realtime database rules section` and then grant permission.

Comment: Do you have any way to recognize users to know if they are from 1 to 20 for instance ?

Comment: When user login(`not firebase auth`) they enter a code[`code-1` or `code-2` or `code-3`], I can recognize them in app. But how do I send the `entered code by user` to firebase before giving access?

Answer (score 0):

Two options come to mind:

1. **Security through obscurity**: Rename `code-1` to something unguessable like `c17357345db9` and rename `code-2` to `64af7b679319`.  Then share a link to an app that gives access to `c17357345db9` to users 1-20, then share a different link for `64af7b679319` to users 21-40.
2. **Create an API Server**: Don't allow direct access to the RTDB but instead create a Cloud Function that acts as a REST API to retrieve the data based on the user's ID.

Neither are optimal and user 3 could easily share access with user 30 if they wanted to.

Comment: I don't want to use `Firebase authentication`. By the way what do I do inside `cloud function`?

Comment: Both of these are options that don't require Firebase authentication.  In Cloud Function you'd just need to intercept the request, validate it and then return the data.

Comment: But I don't have user ID

Comment: You cannot "grant permission" without authentication or even at a minimum user IDs.  If you want to give access to specific nodes to completely anonymous users, somehow grouped into 1-20, 21-40, etc go with option 1.

Comment: In my app user enter `code-1` or `code-2` or `code-3` when entering first time. Can I do something based on their input[entered code]?